what should i do with this error ? AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence'
I am trying to make a discord bot via python however I encounter about 100 lines of error in my terminal the last line of which says: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence'
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="| ", intents=intents)

TOKEN = 'MyToken'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

bot.run(TOKEN)


(BTW, I HAVE added this bot to my server but it's offline)
The full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 494, in finish_recv
    return ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1025, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1103, in create_connection     
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1133, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 286, in _loop_reading      
    length = fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 826, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 498, in finish_recv
    raise ConnectionResetError(*exc.args)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 664, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 374, in from_client
    socket = await client.http.ws_connect(str(url))
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 550, in ws_connect
    return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 835, in _ws_connect
    resp = await self.request(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 581, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 944, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1257, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1226, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1033, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host gateway.discord.gg:443 ssl:default [The specified network name is no longer available]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Programming\Python\My Own Projects\Discord Bot.py", line 13, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete     
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 858, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 787, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in connect
    sequence=self.ws.sequence,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence'

Based on some videos that I watched from YT, it was supposed to run perfectly fine, print the corresponding message in terminal and turn the bot Online in discord so after that I could start making some commands for it and...

Have you read this: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/6037

This error basically means that the code tried accessing 'sequence' within a
'NoneType' object, meaning, it basically tried doing None.sequence which is not possible. I ran your code on Python 3.11.5 and latest discord.py and it seemed to work fine. Try updating your discord.py and updating Python.

It isn't working for me, I installed python 3.11.5 as u said and upgraded discord.py to its latest version but it is still giving me the same error.
I even tried changing my TOKEN but that didn't help.
thanks for your help tho.
